# How convert Integer to Timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I have this integer: `1514761200000` who I want to convert into the timestamp. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 13):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1514761200000)
```

and returns

```
Row f0_  
1   2017-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: I have this error:`invalidQuery: timestamp overflow: TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(15646104000000)`

Comment: @SInsansun I see you're using `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` instead of the proposed `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS`

Answer (score -1):

I hope it helps:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(timestamp_column as INT64)/1000000 AS INT64)) AS converted
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```